# Macbook keyboard backlight doesn't work

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

The keyboard of my Macbook Pro mid-2010 has stopped illuminating in low light.

I checked my System Preferences of my Mountain Lion and there is no "Automatically illuminate keyboard in low light" at all. Also F5 and F6 don't work either while F3 or something like that works perfectly.

I googled this question, and everywhere writes that there is a special point in system pref, which i dont have. [screen](http://www.screencast.com/t/51ZTXFPos) Any suggestions on how to identify/fix the problem are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For all kind of hardware-related issues, I will recommend that following,

Reset your SMC, NVRAM. You can find guides for SMC [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964), NVRAM [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379).

If that doesn't help, boot into Safe Mode, you can the guide [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455).

The last step, is of course, to Time Machine it and reinstall the OS. **Reinstall, not upgrade**.

The very last thing is Genius, or repair it.

**Update: some other fixes**

I forgot the following things to do before giving up.

a) Create a new user account and see if it works

b) Clear your cache with things like CleanMyMac or other free alternatives.

Comment: During resetting SMC and NVRAM keyboard light for a second but then go out. 
Safe mode didn't help too.
And of course i didnt do any backups(i am idiot, i will do backups, i am idiot, i will do backups,i am idiot, i will do backups)

Comment: @ratkke I added two things to try, try them!

Comment: It didn't work either. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon the same issue and here is my suggestion for MacBook Pro Mid 2010 under Mac OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

Just uncheck 'Adjust keyboard brightness in low light"
[enter link description here](http://f.cl.ly/items/2s0m2p1L2w3m0M2d0q2R/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-27%20at%2010.25.31%20AM.jpg)

Comment: I wrote in question that i don't have this point in system pref.